# Request.Form for a textarea returns bad data

Tags: iis, firefox, forms, asp-classic, vbscript

This is a very weird error ocurring only with Firefox 3.5. I have tested it for IE, Safari and Chrome revealing no errors.

I'm using my localhost IIS 5.1 and ye old asp.

I've been able to reduce the scope to this... I have a textarea  in a form, filled with 4000 characters, for example.

< textarea name="obs" id="obs" cols="75" rows="10">...< /textarea >

I submit it to page.asp.

In this example page I just make:

```
    response.Write Request.Form( "obs" )
    response.End
```

80% of times, firefox fails to end loading (waiting for localhost...) and I see that the string "Server:Microsoft-IIS/5.1Date:Tue,01Sep200915:55:01GMTContent-Type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" has been inserted in a random place inside text. In addition, the end of the text is cropped (I suppose that's what firefox is waiting for...).

When firefox loads normally the server string is not included.

Of course I cannot write this data to the database... ;-D

Thanx for reading and I will appreciate any idea about it.

EDIT: I have restarted my PC and disabled all firefox plugins and extensions and the error keeps "working" :-(

Comment: I guess something if not working right in your machine (corrupted memory, bad drivers, whatever)

Comment: Sure! I just tried on a production server this test.asp Anthony kindly posted and of course no error. I haven't made this test. Thanx

So i suppose the error is in my IIS installation, not firefox installation...

Comment: I've been messing with IIS Manager. I rip off the "Content-Type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" part from the responses because I have as a custom HTTP header. I deleted it and it was gone.

But the problem is still here, I keep receiving the "Server:Microsoft-IIS/5.1Date:Tue,01Sep200915:55:01GMT" part.

Answer (score 3):

Its a bit strange.  I've done some testing and I'm not getting the same problem.

At a guess you have response buffering set to false in ASP but FF is not comprehending the resulting chunked encoding.  Why your copy of FF isn't coping I don't know since it works fine on my 3.5 version with or without chunked encoding.

Can you improve the quality the reproduction details in your question.  I'm using the this ASP page as a test:-

```
<%
If Request.QueryString("function") = "post" Then
    Response.Buffer = False
    Response.Write Request.Form("obs")
    Response.End
End If 
%>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form action="test.asp?function=post" method="post">
    <textarea name="obs" id="obs" cols="75" rows="10">
              <!-- Loads of text here -->
    </textarea >
    <input type="submit" value="go" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I really appreciate.
I implemented your test page and get the error! 

The Response.Buffer = False has no effect (i tried on true as well  :-P). I also tried to enable and disable IIS buffer.

Sorry but Firefox is 3.5.2.

Really lost... thanks very much again!

Comment: I'm not sure what to say, the only difference I've got is I'm using IIS7, when I get a chance I'll spin up XP and try my test page there.

Comment: Thanks very much but I'm not sure if it deserves any effort.
I suppose this is a very weird bug on the format firefox sends a textarea filled with a good amount of data.
I'm not sure if I should close the question o leave it unresolved for people who could find the same error. Perhaps I should insert a resume of our findings.